# Best practices Database migration AWS OpsWorks/RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-migration, aws-opsworks, amazon-rds

I have a question regarding some best practices and available tools concerning db migrations (upgrade db schema for the next release):

We currently use one server where we also host our mysql database. If we want to deploy a new release, we push the database migrations with the code to the server, where we use a migration script to alter the database and save the currently deployed database migration (number) in a file.
Now we want to move our system to AWS and use the benefits of horizontal scaling. We can't use our current database migration script with this new system, because multiple servers would be accessing the same database (AWS RDS).

We eventually want to use AWS OpsWorks for the server management and setup new servers with chef scripts. But I didn't find yet a solution how we can deploy automatically our database migrations to the production database.
Do you have any tipps or ideas?

Thanks a lot.

P.S. I think this shouldn't be an uncommon problem, but if I google "DB migration AWS", I always get the AWS service to migrate a database from a different server to AWS, but this serves a different purpose ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Fflyway for migrations in a very similar configuration:
https://flywaydb.org/

Nothing AWS specific, but flyway keeps a table of migrations so only the first node up would actually run the migration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. On which server would you run the migration, if you have multiple webservers? And how would you prevent, that if one server migrates the db, the other servers don't try to migrate the database too or try to acccess it?

Comment: It does not matter. The first server up would run the migrations while other would be locked.